# What music plays at 4:50 of FMA Brotherhood episode 61?

Tags: music, fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

I listened all the soundtracks and could not find it. What music is this?

(I don't mean Sid-Rain. I mean the music before Rain plays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song is "The Intrepid". [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_scbziJUEog)'s a YouTube video.

It is the 7th track of the [Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood Original Soundtrack 3](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Fullmetal_Alchemist_Brotherhood_Original_Soundtrack_3).